# how to read data from metteler toredo scale device?

Tags: python

I purchased the metteler toledo device and connect to windows machine and I am doing programming in python.Using python I am just reading values from that device.I am doing this code on windows os.
following is python code.

```
import serial
from threading import Thread,Lock
import time
from os import listdir


def __init__(self):
    print "init called"
    Thread.__init__(self)
    self.lock = Lock()
    self.scalelock = Lock()
    self.status = {'status':'connecting', 'messages':[]}
    self.input_dir = 'COM1'
    self.weight = 0
    self.weight_info = 'ok'
    self.device = None

def lockedstart(self):
    with self.lock:
        if not self.isAlive():
            self.daemon = True
            self.start()

def set_status(self, status, message = None):
    if status == self.status['status']:
        if message != None and message != self.status['messages'][-1]:
            self.status['messages'].append(message)
    else:
        self.status['status'] = status
        if message:
            self.status['messages'] = [message]
        else:
            self.status['messages'] = []

    if status == 'error' and message:
        print 'Scale Error: ',message
    elif status == 'disconnected' and message:
        print 'Disconnected Scale: ',message

def get_device(self):
    try:

            return serial.Serial(
                    port=0, 
                    baudrate = 9600, 
                    bytesize = 8, 
                    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE, 
                    parity   = serial.PARITY_EVEN, 
                    #xonxoff  = serial.XON,
                    timeout  = 0.01, 
                    writeTimeout= 0.01,

                )

    except Exception as e:
        self.set_status('error',str(e))
        return None

def get_weight(self):
    self.lockedstart()
    return self.weight

def get_weight_info(self):
    self.lockedstart()
    return self.weight_info

def get_status(self):
    self.lockedstart()
    return self.status

def read_weight(self):
    with self.scalelock:
        if self.device:
            self.device.close()
            self.device.open()
            try:
                self.device.write('Z')
                #self.device.write('T')

                self.device.write('W')
                time.sleep(0.1)
                answer = []

                while True:
                    print "device info",self.device
                    char = self.device.read(1)
                    if not char: 
                        break
                    else:
                        answer.append(char)

                if '?' in answer:
                    stat = ord(answer[answer.index('?')+1])
                    if stat == 0: 
                        self.weight_info = 'ok'
                    else:
                        self.weight_info = []
                        if stat & 1 :
                            self.weight_info.append('moving')
                        if stat & 1 << 1:
                            self.weight_info.append('over_capacity')
                        if stat & 1 << 2:
                            self.weight_info.append('negative')
                            self.weight = 0.0
                        if stat & 1 << 3:
                            self.weight_info.append('outside_zero_capture_range')
                        if stat & 1 << 4:
                            self.weight_info.append('center_of_zero')
                        if stat & 1 << 5:
                            self.weight_info.append('net_weight')
                else:
                    answer = answer[1:-1]
                    if 'N' in answer:
                        answer = answer[0:-1]
                    try:
                        self.weight = float(''.join(answer))
                    except ValueError as v:
                        self.set_status('error','No data Received, please power-cycle the scale');
                        self.device = None

            except Exception as e:
                self.set_status('error',str(e))
                self.device = None

def set_zero(self):
    with self.scalelock:
        if self.device:
            try: 
                self.device.write('Z')
            except Exception as e:
                self.set_status('error',str(e))
                self.device = None

def set_tare(self):
    with self.scalelock:
        if self.device:
            try: 
                self.device.write('T')
            except Exception as e:
                self.set_status('error',str(e))
                self.device = None

def clear_tare(self):
    with self.scalelock:
        if self.device:
            try: 
                self.device.write('C')
            except Exception as e:
                self.set_status('error',str(e))
                self.device = None

def run(self):
    self.device   = None

    while True: 
        if self.device:
            self.read_weight()
            time.sleep(0.05)
        else:
            with self.scalelock:
                self.device = self.get_device()
            if not self.device:
                time.sleep(5)

s=Scale()
s.run()
```

Please co operate with me for doing

Comment: What error are you getting / what problems do you have?

Comment: there is no error in program but not getting scale from that device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for meteller toledo device input parameter is
self.device.write('W\r\n')